# UIImage not converting NSData properly

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uiimage, nsdata

I am working on an app using Parse as backend. Whenever I try to load an image the NSData that I get is not empty but whenever I try converting it to an UIImage the image I get is **nil**.

I already checked all the images on Parse and I can see/get all of them from the database. I also re-uploaded the images just in case something was wrong with them.

Here is the piece of code I get the NSData and convert it to UIImage:

```
let myImage = object.objectForKey("imagem") as! PFFile
myImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({(imageData : NSData?, error : NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    if let imageData = imageData{
                            if let newImage = UIImage(data: imageData){
                                myClass.imagem = newImage
                            }    
                        }
                    }
                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                })
```

Comment: How are you converting your image into data?

Comment: where do you check whether the image is nil or not ? `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock()` is an async function which could lead to your observation. The function is not finished when you check your image. So please provide the information where you checked if the image is nil or not.

Comment: Whenever I upload the image on Parse it gets converted I guess. I have already done this process a couple of times with success.

Comment: This is either a problem with how you're checking whether or not the image is nil or a problem with how you're saving the image in the first place.  Either way, the problem isn't with this code.

Comment: I printed the NSData to the logs and also made an if(imageData != nil). I get the NSData, but whenever I convert it to UIImage is nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the way I was doing was correct, but I was working through a proxy and whenever the data was being sent to my app it was not returning the full NSData. So the problem lies within the proxy and not the code. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

try this code. I hope it will help you.

```
let userImageFile = anotherPhoto["imageFile"] as PFFile

userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock 
{
    (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil 
    {
        if let imageData = imageData 
        {
           let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
        }
    }
}
```

For more details , you can refer parse documentation. see this https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#files-images

Answer (score 0):

Try using following code snippet

```
if let imageData = imageData 
{
 var newImage : UIImage! = UIImage(data: imageData!)
 if image
 {
   myClass.imagem = newImage 
 } 
}
```